# Populate Jquery tab with data from database based on dropdown choice

Tags: php, mysql

I want to populate a JQuery footer tab (slide up) with users from my database based on the selection of a dropdown.

The options will be beginner, intermediate, advanced in the drop down and there will be a column in the database with one of the three.

I dont want to refresh the page as it will close the tab.

What is the best way to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: AJAX, with jQuery would be the simplest solution to get started with. Look into jquery methods of `.change` and `.ajax`. The write something up and play with it like Patrick suggests. You'll get there, learning is better than having it handed to you.

Comment: By learning how to code, and then make an attempt.  You need to come here with a starting point, and ask about a specific problem you're having.